# Using built-in queue class of C++ to work within a class I create

Tags: c++

For some reason, I can't seem to get the built-in queue class of C++ to work within a class I create in the way the same built-in queue works in main. I want the queue I use in my class to contain the values of the variables I add to it. But when I use the built-in queue in my class, the queue seems instead to contain something else, maybe addresses of the variables.

What am I doing wrong please?

```
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class Myclass {

private:
    queue<int> q;

public:
    Myclass();
    void qPush(int n){ q.push(n); }
    int qFront(){ q.front(); }
    void qPop(){ q.pop(); }
};

Myclass::Myclass() { // Default Constructor

} 

int main () {
    int num1 = 0; 
    int num2 = 1;

    queue<int> myQ; 
    myQ.push(num1); 
    myQ.push(num2); 
    cout << myQ.front() << endl;
    myQ.pop();  
    cout << myQ.front() << endl;

    cout << "Myclass version: " <<endl; 
    Myclass b;  
    b.qPush(num1);
    b.qPush(num2);
    cout << b.qFront() << endl;  // I want this to print out an int. But it looks like it may be printing out an address instead?
    b.qPop();
    cout << b.qFront() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output I get:

```
0
1
Myclass version:
537168208
537168212
```

Comment: You are not returning anything from `MyClass::qFront`.

Comment: I'm surprised your compiler didn't warn you about this.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `MyClass::qFront()` doesn't have a return statement, and because of that it returns a garbage value.

You just need to add the `return` statement:

```
int qFront(){ return q.front(); }
```

---

To make this code work better you could also add `const` qualifier to make the method usable with const objects:

```
int qFront() const { return q.front(); }
```

Here is an example which demonstrates why it might be necessary:

```
Myclass a;  
a.qPush(42);
const MyClass b = a;
cout << b.qFront(); // This line results in a error if the method isn't marked as const.
```

The rule here is that you should always mark methods that don't modify object state as `const` (if you don't have a good reason to do otherwise).

You could also add a second version *(overload)* of this function which would return a reference to int instead of actual int:

```
int qFront() const { return q.front(); }
int &qFront() { return q.front(); }
```

Then the first one would be used for const objects and the second one would be used for mutable ones.

Because it returns a reference to int instead of just a plain int, you could modify the returned value:

```
Myclass a;  
a.qPush(42);
cout << a.qFront();
a.qFront() = 13;
cout << a.qFront();
```

(Note that compiler wouldn't allow you to write `int &qFront() const { return q.front(); }`, because it would allow you to modify contents of const objects, which is a bad thing.)

Comment: `int qFront(){ return q.front(); }` is perfectly fine.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Looks better in his code. The `return` statement is missing. Please take off this down vote.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat And the reference and const reference permits to take full advantage of `std::queue::front()`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat My answer is what I call `good c++`. My answer is right, solves his problem, and gives him even a bit more. So.. ??

Comment: You got my downvote because I think that the first thing this answer should have is a simple explanation of where the typo is and how to fix it. Only then I would suggest improvements to the code. See the edit I made. (I decided to replace `const int &` with plain `int` because returning a reference to such a small type is no faster then returning the object itself.)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat a `int` is effectively better than a`const int&`, and would have done that in my own code. But I especially did it like that here, to point out the fact that `std::queue::front()` returns a reference or a constant reference. The intention was to help the asker to think about it.